# android alertdialog pause activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have activity code into which I want to add a conditional AlertDialog.
I'm too new to Android development to t know if this 'Regular' code qualifies as "UI" code or not, but the onCreate() has a line of code:

```
**setContentView(R.layout.plateform);**
```

Regardless, I want the 'Regular' code to wait/pause in its execution until the user clicks on one of the AlertDialog buttons.

Currently the AlertDialog launches fine and appears on-screen.
BUT it only stays there for about 2 seconds and then disappears without any user input
And then the code continues on as though the AlertDialog were never there.

I need that user input to be used in 'Regular' code that follows.

How can I get this to work?

The following is the code with the New code inserted followed by the 'Regular' code:

```
private void EnterClick() {
    EditText plate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlate);
    String newString = plate.getText().toString();

    //  =======  **NEW Code**  ==============
    if (!newString.equals("")) {
        // Check If Plate PAID status should be checked at ClientSite
        String UseClientChk = WorkingStorage.GetCharVal(Defines.ClientFlag, getApplicationContext());
        // If appropriate, check Plate number @ Client
        if (UseClientChk.equals("YES")) {
            newString = checkClient(newString);
        }
    }
    // =========================================

    // Below here 'regular' code executes fine 'as is'
    if (!newString.equals("")) {
       // Other 'Regular' code here....
    }
```

New CheckClient code:

```
protected String checkClient(String plate) {
    // Make Web Service call to the Client's Website
    final String ClientChkVehicleURL = "https://dlskfjdslfkjasdlkfjsdlfk/vehicle/";  // DEVELOPMENT URL
    String PlateStatus = "";
    String ReturnMessage = "";
    ReturnMessage = HTTPFileTransfer.HTTPGetPageContent(ClientChkVehicleURL + plate , getApplicationContext());
    try{
        ReturnMessage = ReturnMessage.toString();
        if (ReturnMessage.length() > 0) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(ReturnMessage);
            //String mThisDeviceName = (obj.getString("DeviceId"));   // Code Model
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "ERROR: " + e, e);
    }

    if (PlateStatus.equals("PAID")) {
        // IF PAID, pop AlertDialog "Continue" or "Abort"
        processingAlert = true;
        PopIt("ClientSite","PAID at ClientSite");
    } else if (PlateStatus.equals("NOTPAID")) {
        // IF NOT PAID, AlertDialog "Not Paid at ClientSite"
        processingAlert = true;
        PopIt("ClientSite","NOT PAID at ClientSite");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Plate: " + plate.trim() + " Not Found at ClientSite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return plate;
}
```

And finally the New AlertDialog code:
The following is only TEST code for now to ensure that things work.

```
public void PopIt( String title, String message ){
    // Set Flag to Stay In Alert Window
    String positiveBtnText = "";
    String negativeBtnText = "";
    if (! WorkingStorage.GetCharVal(Defines.LanguageType,getApplicationContext()).equals("SPANISH")) {
        // ENGLISH
        positiveBtnText = "CONTINUE";
        negativeBtnText = "ABORT";
    } else {
        // SPANISH
        positiveBtnText = "CONTINUAR";
        negativeBtnText = "ANULAR";
    }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle( title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    //do stuff onclick of POSITIVE
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on POSITIVE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    processingAlert = false;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    //do stuff onclick of NEGATIVE
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NEGATIVE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    processingAlert = false;
                }
            }).show();
}
```

All of the code above is in the same Plateform Class

How can I get the AlertDialog to stay on-screen and wait for the User Input before going on to executing the 'regular' code?

Answer (score 0):

The whole code is running on UI thread.

Are you starting a new Activity after the statement : //other 'Regular' code here..

My guess is either you are finishing the current Activity or starting a new one which makes the dialog flash for a second.

try:

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle( title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    //do stuff onclick of POSITIVE
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on POSITIVE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    processingAlert = false;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    //do stuff onclick of NEGATIVE
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NEGATIVE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    processingAlert = false;
                }
            });

alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: I'll have to try your suggestion on the next one.   In order to get things working quickly I ended up re-architecturing Iis that a word??) the code so that the subsequent "Regular" code was put into its own Function and ended up being called within the PositiveButton's OnClick().   That caused things to WORK.    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KOTLIN
What worked for me was to set up the alert dialog and then have the subsequent code run out of the alert dialog. Now as  I look at my screen I see a button to click. I want to do nothing unless I say it is ok to proceed and so it looks like this to make it very simple.
eg

```
binding.Btn.setOnClickListener { funXDialog(A, B) }
```

then

```
 fun funXDialog(A:B) {

val contextX = requireContext()
val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(contextX)
alert.setTitle("Title")
alert.setMessage("message")
  
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK")) { _, 
     _ ->
        funX(A,B) // execute the function if the positive button is pressed
    }

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel") {_, _ ->
     funDoNothing() // if the cancel button is pressed.
    }

    alert.show()


}}
```

I am working out of a fragment. This way I get the user to pause execution until he decides what to do.  This work likes a charm. One thing to note --- the funXDialog works if it, and the functions it calls are  set up in the calling fragment and not somewhere else.